# Create list/node class Python

Tags: python

As exercise, I would like to create my own node/list class. Anyway I don't understand how to add a node to list...here's my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.element = value
        self.nextEl = None

    def getEl(self):
        return self.element

    def getNext():
        return self.nextEl

class List:
    def __init__(self, fnode):
        self.firstNode = fnode

    def add(self, newNode):

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.firstNode
        while (temp != None):
            print temp.element
            temp = temp.nextEl
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to find the last node without a `.nextEl` pointer and add the node there:

```
def add(self, newNode):
    node = self.firstNode
    while node.nextEl is not None:
        node = next.nextEl
    node.nextEl = newNode
```

Because this has to traverse the whole list, most linked-list implementations also keep a reference to the last element:

```
class List(object):
    first = last = None

    def __init__(self, fnode):
        self.add(fnode)

    def add(self, newNode):
        if self.first is None:
            self.first = self.last = newNode
        else:
            self.last.nextEl = self.last = newNode
```

Because Python assigns to multiple targets from left to right, `self.last.nextEl` is set to `newNode` before `self.last`.

Some style notes on your code:

- Use `is None` and `is not None` to test if an identifier points to `None` (it's a singleton).
- There is no need for accessors in Python; just refer to the attributes directly.
- Unless this is Python 3, use new-style classes by inheriting from `object`:

  ```
  class Node(object):
      # ...
  ```

Comment: Thank you! Very useful! And Should I want to add a Node not to the end but in the middle or in an arbitrary position?

Comment: @user1576208: `newNode.nextEl, someNode.nextEl = someNode.nextEl, newNode` inserts a node before `someNode`.